# Is there a way to map users to individual graphs in Gremlin server?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I am setting up multiple graph mappings to an OrientDB database in Gremlin server. However, I can't find what to script in Groovy plus what to configure in the configuration yaml file in order to be able to map each authenticated user to a single graph, rather than have all the users validated by the authenticator be able to access everything. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gremlin Server does not provide any features for authorization - only authentication. You would have to build something yourself to handle restricting users to different graphs (or other constraints). That would mean building two things:

1. A custom `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` to handle authorization - maybe called `AuthorizationHandler`
2. A custom `Channelizer` implementation to wire in your custom authorizer to the pipeline - maybe called `AuthorizingChannelizer`

The `AuthorizationHandler` would basically just override Netty's `channelRead()` method

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof RequestMessage){
        RequestMessage requestMessage = (RequestMessage) msg;

        // examine contents of RequestMessage to see what is being requested
        // e.g. the graph - the user information will be there too but 
        // depending on the authentication method you're using you might need
        // to re-decode it at this time as it doesn't appear that the authenticated
        // user is placed on the ChannelHandlerContext for some reason. i made
        // a note to change that as it seems helpful and is a simple enough thing 
        // to do
    }
}
```

For the `AuthorizingChannelizer` you would basically extend the `WebSocketChannelizer` and override the `configure()` method:

```
@Override
public void configure(ChannelPipeline pipeline) { 
    super.configure(pipeline);

    // add an instance of your `AuthorizingChannelizer` to the end of the 
    // netty pipeline which will put it after the `AuthenticationHandler`
    // but before all the Gremlin processing/execution
    pipeline.addLast("authorizier", authorizingChannelizer); 
}
```

Then, in your Gremlin Server config you replace the `channelizer` setting with the fully qualified name of your `AuthorizingChannelizer`. Assuming you've placed your jar containing that class in Gremlin Server's path it should create an instance of it at startup.

I would look at the existing "[handler](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/ec01b6b8120484011130f35362c9c76fa4e13c24/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/handler)" and "[channelizer](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/ec01b6b8120484011130f35362c9c76fa4e13c24/gremlin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/channel)" code for more inspiration on how to make this happen.